# PHP arrays: cross data

Tags: php, arrays

An student here who needs help with the logic of the following:

I have two arrays.

$array1 contains the ids of the places the user has been to.

$array2 contains the ids of the places where the user can obtain one point just by visiting them

Now I need to know if the user has visited any of the places where he/she can get one point so I can grant it to him/her.
How can I do that?

Tnaks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you want to try [array_intersect](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$intersection = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 4):

`count(array_intersect($array1, $array2))` should then give you the number of suych places.

Comment: Well, this was the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$visited = array('1','2','3','4','5'); // and so on
$awarding = array('3','4','5'); //...

$nr_of_grants = 0;

foreach ($visited as $visit)
{
  if(in_array($visit,$awarding)
  {
    $nr_of_grants++;
  }
}

echo "You've been awarded for".$nr_of_grants."places";  //
```

Comment: He. I was writing this same answer :)

Comment: This is less efficient than using `array_intersect`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `array_intersect($array1, $array2)`. The result would be the ids of places present in both arrays.